# Weird string comparasion only on linux

Tags: java

I am facing a weird situation specific on linux.

I had an executable .jar solution running on a windows server then we had to make a move on the same project to a scheduled ejb and deploy on linux.

Well, the project basically reads a .CSV file and convert each line on a List of Pojos which shall be persisted on a Oracle Database. Very simple.

The problem is that the separator of the .csv file is the character "¿" (an inverted question mark). And I am facing issues to split it.

I have tried a couple of changes but none of them is working.

So here is it the original solution:

```
public List<Pojo> readCsv(final String fullPath)
        throws InvalidCsvPattern, Exception {


    final List<Pojo> items = new ArrayList<>();
    final Path path = Paths.get(fullPath);

    if (Files.exists(path)) {

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fullPath);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr)) {

            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (StringUtils.isBlank(line))
                    continue;
                LOG.info("Reading line: " + line);//debugging 
                if (line.startsWith("Client Stuff")) {//indicates that is the header
                    checkLayout(line);
                    continue;
                }

                final Pojo item = lerline(line);
                if (item != null) {
                    items.add(item);
                }
            }

        } catch (final InvalidCsvPattern e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Exception reading csv: ", e);
        }

    }

    return items;
}
```

I have tried reading using UTF-8 but it make worse because all the other lines have special characters with accent. Don't know why but using UTF_8 makes all accents as "?". Using ISO_8859_1 the problem is that I can't "find" the inverted question mark on method "checkLayout()"

The "checkLayout" method is:

```
private void checkLayout(String line) throws FormatacaoPlanilhaInvalidaException {
    final String SEPARATOR = "¿"; //this is outside this method 
    final String[] columns = line.split(SEPARATOR);
    if (columns.length == 0) { //when running on linux this is always true even tho the line has the SEPARATOR character and it's printing perfectly on linux's application servers log.
        throw new InvalidCsvPattern("invalid separator");
    }
    // I have other business rules here but it's not the point atm
}
```

Well, then I decided to change do CSVParser but unsuccessfully anyways.

```
public ArrayList<Pojo> transformCsvIntoPojos(File fullPath) {
    ArrayList<Pojo> list = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    Reader reader;
    CSVParser csvParser = null;
    try {
        
        reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fullPath.getPath()), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

        char separator = "¿".charAt(0); //tried this... or only '¿'. None works
        csvParser = new CSVParser(reader,
                CSVFormat.newFormat(separator).withFirstRecordAsHeader().withTrim().withIgnoreEmptyLines());

        for (final CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
            if (csvRecord.get(0).startsWith("Client Stuff")) {
                checkLayoutNew(csvRecord);
                continue;
            }
            //pojo parser itself
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error reading csv: ", e);
    } finally {
        if (csvParser != null) {
            try {
                csvParser.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}

private void checkLayoutNew(CSVRecord csvRecord) throws InvalidCsvPattern{
    if (StringUtils.isAnyEmpty(csvRecord.get(HEADER_A), csvRecord.get(HEADER_B)) {
        throw new InvalidCsvPattern("Invalid columns");
    }
}
```

It looks like the "split" character is understandable using CSVParser but the validation is failling because - and I don't know why - the constaints HEADER_A and HEADER_B are having encoding issues, even they are on the source file...

```
private String HEADER_A = "Número do circuito";
private String HEADER_B = "Número do cliente";
```

and the server log says that:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping for NÃºmero do circuito not found, expected one of [Número do circuito¿Número do cliente¿... a bunch of other columns...]
```

So.... you guys have any idea why this is not working and how to solve this?

Comment: "when running on linux this is always true" that suggests either the string is empty, or it consists entirely of `¿` characters. What is the content of the string?

Comment: Have you tried quoting the character, `line.split(Pattern.quote(SEPARATOR));`?

Comment: NB: `"¿".charAt(0)` is more easily written as `'¿'`.

Comment: First you do `final String[] columns = line.split(SEPARATOR);`, then you check a *different variable* which is not `columns`: `if (colunas.length == 0)`

Comment: I suggest you open a hex editor and see whether the separator character is *actually* `¿`. It *could* be a character set issue.

Comment: hey @AndyTurner. The content of the string is the same printed on the bottom of the question. "Número do circuito¿Número do cliente¿[... a lot a columns here]". And yes, I tried quoting the caracter. I agree with you replacing `"¿".charAt(0)` but for some reason maven is not building the project when I use `'¿'`.

Comment: yes @VGR I edited the question. It was the same variable btw.

Comment: If `'¿'` causes a build failure, the problem is likely not the charset of the CSV file.  The problem is likely that your source file is UTF-8, but the compiler thinks it’s ISO-8859-1 or some other ISO-8859-n or windows-125n charset. Make sure your IDE knows the source files are UTF-8 files (or tell your editor to save them in the charset that the compiler is expecting).

Comment: that's it @VGR! I changed maven compile source and the project's encoding aswell. Both to ISO-8859-1. Now everything works. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all your files use the correct encoding. You can use `xxd` or [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=To_Hexdump(16,false,false,false)) to find out how your characters are encoded to bytes.